# Downloading files without fileDownloadActionListener

Tags: oracle-adf

To download a file without using fileDownloadActionListener I add a button on a page:

```
<af:commandButton text="Download" id="cb1" partialSubmit="true" actionListener="#{bean.downloadListener}"/>
```

and in the action listener I write the following:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
ec.redirect("http://download-server/file");
fc.responseComplete();
```

The problem is, **after the first download the button stops responding to clicks**.

I've also tried writing the data to the response stream like this:

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();
ec.responseReset();
ec.setResponseContentType("application/xls");
ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report.xls\"");
OutputStream out = ec.getResponseOutputStream();
// write the data
out.close();
fc.responseComplete();
```

and even getting an HttpServletResponse:

```
HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse)ec.getResponse();
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report.xls\"");
resp.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/xls");
OutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
// write the data
out.close();
fc.responseComplete();
```

but neither works.

What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this using a bit of JavaScript:

```
final FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();    
final ExtendedRenderKitService erks =
    Service.getService(fc.getRenderKit(), ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
erks.addScript(fc, String.format("window.location = '%s';", escapeSingleQuotes(url)));
```

Or, instead of assigning `window.location`, download using an inline frame:

```
erks.addScript(
    fc,
    String.format("var downloadUrl = '%s';", escapeSingleQuotes(url)) +
    "var frame = document.createElement('iframe');" +
    "frame.setAttribute('src', downloadUrl);" +
    "frame.style.border = '0';" +
    "frame.style.clip = 'rect(0 0 0 0)';" +
    "frame.style.width = '1px';" +
    "frame.style.height = '1px';" +
    "frame.style.margin = '-1px';" +
    "frame.style.padding = '0';" +
    "frame.style.position = 'absolute';" +
    "document.body.appendChild(frame);"
);
```